# Checking my array for an item using indexOf() is returning an undefined error when i try to use it

Tags: javascript, database, react-native

When i call `checkInList()` in my React Native app I get the error:

> `TypeError`: Cannot read property `indexOf` of undefined

I think there maybe an issue in that i've got an object like array, instead of an array?

The `myList[]` appears to be an object not an array, so i don't know if that's why `indexOf` isn't working? What can i do about it? I need this to run quite fast and quickly check. Are there any alternatives?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    myList: []
  }
}
// get string list from DynamoDB and set it locally to myList
assign() {
  this.setState({myList: userData.data.getlist.mylistfromDB}); 
}
// Then check if my string is in the list i just set 
checkInList() {
  if (this.state.myList.indexOf("sj8w73hhs6s") > -1) {
    // In the list!
  } else {
    // Not in the list
  }    
}
```

myList contents: 
[image: See List here]

Comment: That's because this is not the react component instance but something else. Try console.log(this)

Comment: That is my console read out when i do console.log(this.state.myList)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the checkInList function before the setState method is being finished so you can include the function call in the callback of setState method like below.

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    myList: []
  }
}
// get string list from DynamoDB and set it locally to myList
assign() {
  this.setState({ myList: userData.data.getlist.mylistfromDB }, ()=> this.checkInList());
}
// Then check if my string is in the list i just set 
checkInList() {
  if (this.state.myList.indexOf("sj8w73hhs6s") > -1) {
    // In the list!
  } else {
    // Not in the list
  }    
}
```

Comment: No i'm using async/await, but i've simplified the code here.

Comment: Ah alright. I guess you must have not bound the function checkInList in your constructor. You can replace your constructor with the code below
`constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    myList: []
  }
this.checkInList = this.checkInList.bind(this);
}`

Comment: myList[] is populated when i call checkInList. I suspect that my issue is with treating the list as an object-like array instead of a proper array. Hence indexOf() won't operate on it. But i'm not sure how to correct it

Comment: Try using this function `checkInList() {var x = this.state.myList.indexOf("sj8w73hhs6s") ;
  if (x > -1) {
    // In the list!
  } else {
    // Not in the list
  }    
}`